# Why is the SFD value 171?

Tags: ethernet

Why is the SFD (Start Frame Delimiter) value 171 (10101011 in binary notation)?

Is it just a constant number?

I'm just curious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ethernet SFD is is a continuation and ending of the preamble. The preamble, from the original ethernet specification, is a series of alternating bits which aided signal synchronization. The SFD continues the synchronization until the last bit, which is a one instead of zero. This one bit marks the end of synchronization.